inserting child to xml file in php not working as expected
I want to add child to existing xml file. I am able to add child components but one child component having data with apersand sign "&" not adding the data and leaving blank. Here is my that part of code
$jobdata->addChild("experience", "<![CDATA[1+ years]]>");
$jobdata->addChild("expirationdate", "<![CDATA[]]>");
$jobdata->addChild("indeed-apply-data", "<![CDATA[indeed-apply-apiToken=xxxxxxx&indeed-apply-jobTitle={$job_title}&indeed-apply-jobId={$job_id}&indeed-apply-jobCompanyName=ISG&indeed-apply-jobLocation={$location['city']}+{$location['state']}&indeed-apply-jobUrl={$encodedPermalink}&indeed-apply-postUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fxxxx.com&indeed-apply-questions={$encodedScreener}]]>");

above code results in this output
<experience>&lt;![CDATA[1+ years]]&gt;</experience><expirationdate>&lt;![CDATA[]]&gt;</expirationdate><indeed-apply-data/>

indeed-apply-data is empty. also right/left arrow symbols are converted to html eitities like &gt;
